# Consuming a web service using JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, api, service

I am looking to create a client browser interface which will utilise the dictionary web service at [Glosbe API](http://glosbe.com/a-api). The user should be able to enter a word or a phrase into an input component and submit it without the page reloading. The returned data needs to be displayed on the page in a usable format so that they are able to find and read the meanings.

I've attempted this by creating a web service through Netbeans but I'm unsure whether this is the right method. Is it as simple as creating a HTML page and using javascript to call the api for Glosbe?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XMLHTTPRequest from javascript to poll a web service. The XHR object is great for allowing you to make a request to a page or submit a form without having to refresh the page. When the request is made, it can be done asynchronously to allow the page to continue with other events and then handle the response and update the HTML. There are tons of resources on google that can instruct you on implementing an XHR object and the proper error handling along with sample code.

As far as the returned data being displayed in a usable format, that would need to be done by your JS when the response comes back. You can parse the response for the data you want and build the appropriate HTML element through JS to update your UI.

HTML

    <input type='text' id='word'>

    <input type='buton' onclick='sendMessage()'>

JS

```
function sendMessage()
{
 var XHRrequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
 XHRrequest.onabort = function() {
 };
 XHRrequest.onloadend = function (evt) {
 };
 XHRrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (XHRrequest.readyState == 4 && XHRrequest.status == 200) {
   //parse XHRrequest.responseText for response and build object
   //this is where you update your UI with an HTML element
  }
  else if (XHRrequest.readyState == 4 && XHRrequest.status!=0) {
   console.log("Error: returned status code " + XHRrequest.status + " " + XHRrequest.statusText + "\r\n" + XHRrequest.responseText);
   //error handling for failed response
  }
 };
 XHRrequest.ontimeout = function() {
  alert("Error: event timed out");
 };
 XHRrequest.open("POST", WEBSERVICE_URL_HERE, true);
 XHRrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 XHRrequest.send("word="+document.getElementById('word').value); \\request data goes here
}
```

Comment: That would allow a user to input a word on the HTML page and that would request a reply from the Glosbe web service?

Comment: So you would set up an input box for the user to type, use either the onkeypress event to listen for an enter or a button and its onclick event to initialize the XHR object. The XHR object would make its request and when it finishes, you would parse that information and create an HTML element in JS with the information returned from the request that would update the UI with whatever you wanted.

Comment: Possible for you to show me a code example of this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write code in a comment, I tried but it came out really bad.

Comment: You obviously need to prepare the request packet in accordance to the web service, and you will need to parse the response in accordance to what you want the response to do, but this is the skeleton of what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: If this request is to a url outside your domain, you will get an error because browsers do not allow cross-site polling. A workaround would be to poll a page on your own server that uses php or asp to retrieve the data server-side.

Comment: The request will be to the glosbe servers using their API, so will this not work? I've not learnt anything about php or asp to be able to do that.

Comment: idk what glosbe is so you'll have to talk to them about the specifics of getting everything integrated. If you aren't familiar with server-side programming and aren't familiar with JS, I suggest you learn them before asking for assistance. I can't/won't do your entire project for you, that is for you to do. I will give you the skeletal structure of the project (which I provided above) for you to get started, move in the right direction, and take the next step.

Comment: If the code above is confusing to you, or you don't know where to go from there or how to use it, your issue isn't what you think it is, your issue is getting too far ahead of yourself and trying to develop a project before you were prepared and educated to do so.

Comment: It's a work in progress, but this is a start. Thank you very much for your help so far.

Comment: Good luck. Google and reading are your friends, do as much as you need to in order to be successful.